# Generate Sencha Touch App Failed

Tags: extjs, installation, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.3

I'm having problem generating new Sencha Touch application. I already downloaded the Sencha SDK, Ruby and Sencha CMD. When I use `sencha` the sencha version and help are printed.

When I use the ff command to generate Sencha Touch application I encountered Build Failed:

> sencha -sdk [sencha sdk location] generate app -name MyApp -path [project location]

Issue:

```
Sencha Cmd v5.0.1.231
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : default
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[ERR] Failed to resolve dependency Ext.app.Application for file MyApp.app.$Application
[ERR] 
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.app.Application
[ERR]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.e
[ERR] xecuteSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
[ERR] 
[ERR] Total time: 1 second
[ERR] 
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] (installation dir)\bin\Sencha\Cmd\5.0.1.231\plugin.xml:303: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERR] (installation dir)\bin\Sencha\Cmd\5.0.1.231\plugins\touch\2.3\plugin.xml:334: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERR] (installation dir)\workspace-sencha\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:373: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERR] (installation dir)\workspace-sencha\.sencha\app\init-impl.xml:258: com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.app.Application
[ERR]   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccesso
[ERR] r23.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR] 
[ERR] Total time: 5 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
(installation dir)\bin\Sencha\Cmd\5.0.1.231\plugins\touch\2.3\plugin.xml:334: The following error occurred while executing this line:
(installation dir)\workspace-sencha\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:373: The following error occurred while executing this line:
(installation dir)\workspace-sencha\.sencha\app\init-impl.xml:258: com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.app.Application
```

I'm already 3 days on this, not sure if I miss something.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the exact command you run? `sencha -sdk touch generate app TouchTest touch-test` works for me with Touch 2.3.1 and Cmd v5.0.1.231

Comment: I can now generate the app without problem. I extracted the SDK to C:\sencha, then it works now. I'm not sure if this really solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try use -d option to see more detail first

```
sencha -d -sdk [sencha sdk location] generate app -name MyApp -path [project location]
```